# Custom registration field data is not visible in magento 1.7

Tags: magento

I am following the instructions [here](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/customer-registration-fields-magento1-6). 
I have created a custom field in magento 1.7 CE, registration field called Mobile.
Its working fine i.e, taking input while the time registration,but while click on my account its not showing the value.
All other field’s values are coming e.g., first name last name email. 
But not in my mobile filed. It is coming as blank.

I know its for v 1.6. but i made it to work on v1.7 somehow.

Comment: Is the attribute stored correctly? Check if it's displayed in backend. Does the attribute exist in `eav_attribute` table?

Answer (score 0):

Did you flush the backend cache? In magento system > configuration > cache page it is the top right orange button. Magento caches the db structure